# Subgroup analysis results are different if I conducted each subgroup separately in metarate in R

Tags: r, meta-analysis, incidence-rate-ratio, metafor

I am doing a single arm meta-analysis of incidence rate using Poisson regression and doing subgroup analysis using `meta` and `metafor` packages in `R`.
Upon reviewing subgroup analysis results, I noticed it is different if I conducted each subgroup separately. If there is any possible explanation for that, it will be greatly appreciated.

Furthermore, I need  to know **what the used statistical test to get the `interaction-P value` or `subgroup difference P value`** is (which is `0.0432` in the following dataset (in random effect model)).

I reviewed this [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/340621/why-am-i-getting-different-means-when-conducting-multilevel-meta-analysis-with-f) but I couldn't get what I need there.
Here is my code and sample dataset

```
library(meta); library(metafor)
data<-read.table(text="studlab  Subgroup_2gps   Mean.FU popXFU  event
DeBonis.2014    Adult   11.5    1552.5  13
Fucci.2007  Adult   6.5 416 4
Ram.2020    Pediatrics  5.583333    290.33333   4
Kadirogullari.2019  Pediatrics  1.616667    90.53333    2
Kashiyama.2014  Pediatrics  3.275   180.125 1
Tomita.2005 Pediatrics  6.708333    134.16667   1
Lawrie.2006 Pediatrics  3.1 291.4   16
Maeda.2019  Pediatrics  5.5 203.5   1
Zussa.1997  Pediatrics  3.05    350.75  2
Murashita.2013  Pediatrics  7.5 562.5   6
David.2013  Pediatrics  10.1    1070.6  30
Bourguignon.2016    Pediatrics  3.4 98.6    3
Phillips.2000   Pediatrics  0.9 66.6    5
Pfannmuller.2013    Pediatrics  4.3 498.8   5
Totaro.1999 Adult   3.833333    199.33333   3
", sep="\t", header=T)


mr <- metarate(event,popXFU, data= data,# subset= data$Subgroup_2gps== "Neochords " ,
               studlab = studlab, method = "GLMM",model.glmm = "CM.EL",method.ci = "Poisson",   irscale = 1000)
mr2<- update (mr, byvar=Subgroup_2gps);forest(mr2); mr2

# Results for subgroups (random effects model):
#   k  events             95%-CI  tau^2    tau
# Subgroup_2gps = Adult        3  9.3998 [ 6.0643; 14.5697]      0      0
# Subgroup_2gps = Pediatrics  12 18.6089 [11.3291; 30.5666] 0.4500 0.6708
# 
# Test for subgroup differences (random effects model):
#   Q d.f. p-value
# Between groups   4.09    1  0.0432

## It gave me IR of 18.6089 [11.3291; 30.5666] for random effect for Pediatrics subgroup

#============================================================================================
mr <- metarate(event,popXFU, data= data, subset= data$Subgroup_2gps== "Pediatrics" ,
               studlab = studlab, method = "GLMM",model.glmm = "CM.EL",method.ci = "Poisson",   irscale = 1000);mr
## It gave me IR of 15.9876 [ 9.5438; 26.7820] for random effect
```

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This has been answered here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-meta-analysis/2022-September/004221.html

Comment: @Wolfgang Thx a lot. Upvoted. Yes, **Guido** mentioned that I have to use the latest version of `meta` and `metafor`. He also mentioned that the test for subgroup differences checks whether the random effects estimates in the two subgroups differ and that I can use metagen() or rma.uni() to calculate the Q statistic and p-value ```## Test for subgroup differences
##
metagen(mr2$TE.random.w, mr2$seTE.random.w)$Q
metagen(mr2$TE.random.w, mr2$seTE.random.w)$pval.Q```